What are the sources for Qisas Al-Anbiya(s)?
It's known that not all prophets and messengers weren't mentioned by name in the Quran. Neither Quran narrates their lives in very great detail.
However, we get some related or corroboratory information from the hadiths.
But none of them are in that great details as they were narrated in Qisas Al-Anbiyas, e.g. by Ibn Kathir.
How did those authors compile the stories of the prophets and messengers? What were their sources?

Ibn Kathir simply quoted his sources in his book, since he shared his chain of transmission either fully or to a known authority or referred to a hadith compilation etc..
